# #Askfirebase Get the previous item values(POJO) in firebase recycler adapter in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

## AskFirebase How to get the previous item values(POJO) in firebase recycler adapter without using database query.

```
// Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post,
            PostViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);
            Log.e(TAG, "populateViewHolder: " + position);
            // Set click listener for the whole post view
            final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Launch PostDetailActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // Determine if the current user has liked this post and set UI accordingly
            if (model.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {

                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
            } else {

                viewHolder.starView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
            }

            // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View starView) {
                    // Need to write to both places the post is stored
                    Log.e(TAG, "new: ");
                    DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("posts").child(postRef.getKey());
                    DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child("user-posts").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());

                    // Run two transactions
                    onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                    onStarClicked(userPostRef);
                }
            });
        }


    };

    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Suppose their are **five** cell list whenever i am facing **second** cell in the list that time i want to put a condition based on **first** cell value. So how i can fatch the value of first cell?

I already try to using arraylist to store the POJO of **Post** . But the problem is whenever some item is deleted from firebase table that item **onDataChange** call but **populateViewHolder** doesn't call. Their is also a way to get previous data using database query that is

```
DatabaseReference ref = getRef(position-1);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "CHild exist: ");
                        
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "no CHild exist: ");
                       
                    }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

But i don't want to use this database query is their any other way?

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do. On second cell in the list that time you want to put a condition based on first cell value. And what do you do on first cell ?

Comment: Okay @eurosecom i want to put some condition in the adapter(within populateViewHolder method) like this- `String prePostedDate = getDateFromTimestamp(msgList.get(position - 1).msg_time);` Here msgList is the arraylist which contain the model. But this is a wrong process. i want to fetch the previous data in the adapter(not using database query).
`(position-1)` denotes the previous position. so in the case i am facing the time of previous cell(if position not 0).
And in postion 0 i just simple visible the view then it will visible based on condition(previous cell value).

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand why do you think that using database query(position-1) is a wrong process.Add addListenerForSingleValueEvent to mDatabase then if itemonDataChange is calling populateViewHolder is calling also.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer you will understand my issue better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Design Firebase data structure for topic Answer and Comment its like your problem.[image]

- gdtdg6765rf and hjgdhs567hd are unique key get by firebase
- hjgdhs567hd is answer
- gdtdg6765rf is comment to answer hjgdhs567hd
- created is -1*UNIX Timestamp for ordering
- date, time and toanswer was saved in comments by answer belong to
- if to delete answer set all flags "deleted=1" where child "toanswer=deleted answer key" to populate again

Comment: Also it's a answer of my actual question.Now as whenever item is deleted adapter is notify so now i can store the value. ☺

Comment: Their is one more problem in firebase recycler adapter that is after loading when i minimize the app at that time if some changes occur when i again resume the app that time the changes doesn't reflect, also after resume if some change occur it doesn't reflect too. do you know why it is happening? I am calling the firebase recycler adapter in the `oncreate` and in `onstop` i just put that checking `if (msgListAdapter != null) {  msgListAdapter.cleanup(); }` .

Comment: Oncreate is called when activity is first created. Try in onStart call if (msgListAdapter != null) {msgListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); will not work because firebase recycler adapter doesn't called notifyDataSetChanged(). SO that will not work. i Found a solution in case of activity i will set adapter to onStart and in case of fragment i will set it on onActivityCreated.
But their is a problem that is in case of activity the changes reflect but in case fragment  changes happen in background.  I don't know why.

Comment: Oh. Here https://github.com/eurosecom/Attendance/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/eusecom/attendance/fragment/AbsenceListFragment.java is my FBrecycler in Fragment. I set adapter to onActivityCreated. It reflect changes in FB by onPause. Watch line 109, difference is that you have not addListenerForSingleValueEvent. Try to add.

Comment: OKay let me put the code in the fragment but what about activity?

Comment: Try to add listener. It's same advice for Activity. Please, If will not work, ask new question like "FBrecycler does not reflect changes after onPause"  to allow other users to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, may be i get your point the way getquery works i have to do this the same actually for FBrecycler i am just passing the query in this way. `Query queryForMsg = mDatabase.child("messages").child(from_msg_channel_id);` not this way `Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);`. I think that's why its not working thanks for so much help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@eurosecom above image is my layout where their is a recycler view which populate through `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` . Now those green cell is my single cell. you see a red circle which denote the date. in case of `position==0` I just simple visible the layout, and in case of `position>0` i want to put the condition based on previous item date.

Now in my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` i have to put the condition so i have to fetch the previous position date. So as i am already doing a network oparetion using `Query` to fetch the msg list i don't want to put `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in the populateview again as because it will again fetch the val from database. So is their any other way to get the previous item?

Comment: Thank you, i understand what you want to do. Please what is JSON Structure your Data in Firebase ? Can you consider save time of item1 in its answer item2 ?

Comment: Yes. Suppose i add the model class(contain the time value) in a arraylist now if suppose some msg is delete. when some item is delete from that recycler view that time *populateViewHolder* doesn't call. Only *onDataChange* call also i can't get the position of deleted item. so for getting the position i need to write listener outside of the adapter.

Comment: That is also a problem of firebase recycler adapter that is as populate view holder doesn't call when item is deleted(but from ui item is delete).

Can you tell me is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes i can use the `Observer` method of recycler view. But how to reload the list?

Comment: FirebaseRecycler populate again only changed items. In your FB data structure save id of item1 in item2. By deleting item1 to set flag delete=1 in item1 and item2 too.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this idea ☺

Comment: Example of Firebase Data structure is in my answer. May be to add child mycomments=List of comments belong to the answer.